# Brackets Node.js

Tags: node.js, adobe-brackets

I know that Brackets has 32 bit Node.js integrated into it's core. And I know how to connect to it but I need to use my external 64 nit Node and I do not know how to connect to it. How can I connect to external Node and not use integrated one?

Comment: why would you need to?

Comment: because i want to make call to 64 bit library and when I'm trying I'm getting error dlopen(...) match-o wrong architecture

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is for something personal and not an extension you're writing.

In that case, you could write a bash script that can call your 64 bit Node. Once the script is working, call it using the brackets' Node.js :

```
function call64bitsNode(options, callback) {
    var command = '/your/bash/script.sh ' + options;
    child_process.exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        callback(err, stdout, stderr);
    });
}
```